# Use asp.net forms authentication so only logged in users can view website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, forms-authentication

Login.aspx, passwordrecovery.aspx, and register.aspx should be the only pages accessible for logged in users.  I have the following in my webconfig:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

I have the following in my configuration element of my webconfig:

```
 <location path="images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="passwordrecovery.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I get an Error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. alert box when viewing any of the public pages.  How do I allow access to the asp.net client-side framework (using the location tags?)?

Comment: I find it easier to configure by having all public resources in my root folder, and all protected resources in a sub folder.

Comment: If you could share some small sample application that would help understand the problem.

Comment: I can easily edit the location tags (comment them out) to make the site pages public or private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked fiddler and added the following:

```
<location path="Telerik.Web.Ui.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Ajax client side framework now loads - error message is gone.  For those not using the Telerik controls - I'm sure you can use something similar to:

```
<location path="WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the actual url that is requested. I think those will be the calls to Webresource.axd.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Greg, put all your public resources in the root and place any protected items in a subfolder.

Ex:

```
<location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="subfolderName">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="myRole" />
            <deny users="*" />

            <!-- deny unknown users -->
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This is for working on the site in development.  Using the location tag I can easily comment out the code and 'open' up the site when it's public.